# Xcode 11 Provisioning profile failed qualification

Tags: xcode

I tried to archive my iOS application using Xcode 11 and stumbled on this issue which I'm unable to fix.

> Profile doesn't include the com.apple.application-identifier and com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlements.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you install macOS Big Sur beta?

Comment: Same issue. Installed Big Sur beta.... 

I even created a new app with the same bundle id and it didn't work.

Comment: Same problem, also Big Sur Beta

Comment: I'm indeed on the macOS Big Sur Developer beta 1

Comment: I had similar problem with Enterprise distribution. After selecting the certificate i can see error "Profile doesn't include the com.apple.application-identifier and com.apple.developer.aps-environment entitlements.". Luckily workaround suggested by @Peter Ruppert  works for me.

Comment: Same issue :(  Big Sur beta 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to upload an iOS 13 build that you were working on in Xcode 11 Previously:

A workaround, for now, is to download Xcode 12 Beta and use that to upload the archive that you made in Xcode 11.

Comment: I do have the Xcode 12 Beta installed, but when uploading archives to the App Store it's only possible to use it for internal TestFlight testers. When I try using that build for external testers or as new version for an application it says 'invalid binary' because the archive has been build with a Beta version of Xcode.

Comment: @T.Haas Did you build the archive in Xcode 12 Beta?  What I mean is to make the build-in Xcode 11 like normal, then open Xcode 12 and open the organizer and upload the build that you made previously. But of course this is for if you are trying to build iOS 13 builds, as I still needed to upload some apps for users to test in iOS 13.

Answer (score 4):

This problem arises in new Mac OS Big Sur, You can use a workaround:

1. Open Xcode 11 and Archive your build.
2. Download Xcode 12 Beta from the link: https://developer.apple.com/download/
3. Extract Xcode and Open Xcode 12 Beta
4. Open Xcode 12 Organizer from

> Menu -> Window -> Organizer

5. Upload the latest Archive.
6. Completed

Comment: Thank you so much <3